# Server side code to reload page through jQuery ajax call in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Automatically reload page through ajax call in PHP. Code should be done at server side not in JS. Is it possible in PHP through ajax call?

Comment: Reload the current document in php: location.reload();

Comment: can you show what have you done so far?

Comment: learn about webhooks

Comment: Yes it is possible. We dont see what you have tried. You try we help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this ajax request in javascript

```
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://yoursite.com/somefile.php?action=reload", true);
    xhttp.send();
```

and this in php

```
if ( isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "reload" ) {
    header("Refresh:0");
 }
```